# sympy term rewriting sqrt and binomial formula

Tags: sympy

I have the following code

```py
import sympy as sp
x, y = sp.symbols('x y', real=True, positive=True)
expr = sp.sqrt(1/(x-y))/sp.sqrt(x+y)
```

the expression created should be equal to sqrt(1/(x^2 - y^2)) and I would like to rewrite it in that form but I cannot figure out how. I tried `.rewrite(sp.sqrt)`, `.rewrite(x**2 - y**2)` and similar stuff but it did not help.

Ty for any tips on this,

Franz

Answer (score 0):

The expression that you want is not equivalent to the one that you have:

```
In [53]: expr1 = sqrt(1/x - y)/sqrt(x + y)

In [54]: expr2 = 1/sqrt(x**2 - y**2)

In [55]: expr1
Out[55]: 
    ________
   ╱      1 
  ╱  -y + ─ 
╲╱        x 
────────────
   _______  
 ╲╱ x + y   

In [56]: expr2
Out[56]: 
     1      
────────────
   _________
  ╱  2    2 
╲╱  x  - y  

In [58]: expr1.subs({x:1, y:2})
Out[58]: 
√3⋅ⅈ
────
 3  

In [59]: expr2.subs({x:1, y:2})
Out[59]: 
-√3⋅ⅈ 
──────
  3
```

That being said it should still be possible to do what you want using `powsimp(expr1, force=True)` but that doesn't seem to work in this case. I recommend opening a bug report about `powsimp`:
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: I forgot a pair of parentheses. I hope it is fixed now.

Comment: Your expressions are still not equivalent. Just substitute the same two values that I showed.

Comment: You need to understand that `1/sqrt(z)` is not equivalent to `sqrt(1/z)` if `z` is not necessarily positive. In your case the condition comes down to whether `x > y`.

Comment: You are of course correct and this is another oversight of mine. I edited the question once again so that `expr2 =sp.sqrt(1/(x**2 - y**2))` and tested your example. I am really sorry for the poorly checked question.